# boost timer binding

Tags: boost, timer

I'm trying to set up a timer using the boost library.

Basically, this is what I wrote:

```
class ContactList {
public:
    ContactList();
    virtual ~ContactList();
    int Start();
    int readFromFile();
    int dumpList();
    void checkContacts(const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void initializeTimer();

private:
    std::list<Contact*> CList;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer dt;
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
};

int ContactList::Start(){
...
this->initializeTimer();
}

void ContactList::checkContacts(const boost::system::error_code& error){
    std::cout<<"__Here we go!"<<std::endl;
    ios.reset();
    initializeTimer();
}

void ContactList::initializeTimer(){
    dt.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(4));
    dt.async_wait(boost::bind( &ContactList::checkContacts, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
    ios.run();
}
```

and the compiler complains a lot, saying:

```
   g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"kad/ContactList.d" -MT"kad/ContactList.d" -o"kad/ContactList.o" "../kad/ContactList.cpp"
../kad/ContactList.cpp: In constructor ‘kad::ContactList::ContactList()’:
../kad/ContactList.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> > >::basic_deadline_timer()’
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:177: note: candidates are: boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<Time, TimeTraits, TimerService>::basic_deadline_timer(boost::asio::io_service&, const typename TimeTraits::duration_type&) [with Time = boost::posix_time::ptime, TimeTraits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, TimerService = boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >]
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:158: note:                 boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<Time, TimeTraits, TimerService>::basic_deadline_timer(boost::asio::io_service&, const typename TimeTraits::time_type&) [with Time = boost::posix_time::ptime, TimeTraits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, TimerService = boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >]
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:142: note:                 boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<Time, TimeTraits, TimerService>::basic_deadline_timer(boost::asio::io_service&) [with Time = boost::posix_time::ptime, TimeTraits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, TimerService = boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >]
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:122: note:                 boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> > >::basic_deadline_timer(const boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> > >&)
/usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp: In member function ‘R& boost::_mfi::dm<R, T>::operator()(T*) const [with R = void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), T = kad::ContactList]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:222:   instantiated from ‘R boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<R>, F&, A&, long int) [with R = void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), F = boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, A = boost::_bi::list1<boost::system::error_code&>, A1 = boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*>]’
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:32:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(A1&) [with A1 = boost::system::error_code, R = void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), F = boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, L = boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> >]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:39:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler, Arg1>::operator()() [with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, Arg1 = boost::system::error_code]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp:63:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke(Function, ...) [with Function = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:39:   instantiated from ‘void boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(const Function&, Context*) [with Function = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>, Context = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:72:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::detail::asio_handler_invoke(const Function&, boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler, Arg1>*) [with Function = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>, Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, Arg1 = boost::system::error_code]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp:39:   instantiated from ‘void boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(const Function&, Context*) [with Function = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>, Context = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_queue.hpp:192:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::asio::detail::handler_queue::handler_wrapper<Handler>::do_call(boost::asio::detail::handler_queue::handler*) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_queue.hpp:172:   instantiated from ‘boost::asio::detail::handler_queue::handler_wrapper<Handler>::handler_wrapper(Handler) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:138:   instantiated from ‘boost::asio::detail::handler_ptr<Alloc_Traits>::handler_ptr(boost::asio::detail::raw_handler_ptr<Alloc_Traits>&, Arg1&) [with Arg1 = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>, Alloc_Traits = boost::asio::detail::handler_alloc_traits<boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>, boost::asio::detail::handler_queue::handler_wrapper<boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code> > >]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_queue.hpp:117:   instantiated from ‘static boost::asio::detail::handler_queue::handler* boost::asio::detail::handler_queue::wrap(Handler) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/task_io_service.hpp:190:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::detail::task_io_service<Task>::post(Handler) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>, Task = boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.ipp:126:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::io_service::post(Handler) [with CompletionHandler = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, boost::system::error_code>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:172:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits, Timer_Scheduler>::wait_handler<Handler>::operator()(const boost::system::error_code&) [with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, Timer_Scheduler = boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/timer_queue.hpp:299:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>::timer<Handler>::complete_handler(boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>::timer_base*, const boost::system::error_code&) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false> >::wait_handler<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > > >, Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/timer_queue.hpp:276:   instantiated from ‘boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>::timer<Handler>::timer(const typename Time_Traits::time_type&, Handler, void*) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false> >::wait_handler<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > > >, Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/timer_queue.hpp:71:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>::enqueue_timer(const typename Time_Traits::time_type&, Handler, void*) [with Handler = boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false> >::wait_handler<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > > >, Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/epoll_reactor.hpp:414:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<Own_Thread>::schedule_timer(boost::asio::detail::timer_queue<Time_Traits>&, const typename Time_Traits::time_type&, Handler, void*) [with Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, Handler = boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false> >::wait_handler<boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > > >, bool Own_Thread = false]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:185:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits, Timer_Scheduler>::async_wait(boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits, Timer_Scheduler>::implementation_type&, Handler) [with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, Timer_Scheduler = boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp:157:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<TimeType, TimeTraits>::async_wait(typename boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<TimeTraits, boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor<false> >::implementation_type&, WaitHandler) [with WaitHandler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, TimeType = boost::posix_time::ptime, TimeTraits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>]’
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp:374:   instantiated from ‘void boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<Time, TimeTraits, TimerService>::async_wait(WaitHandler) [with WaitHandler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void (&)(const boost::system::error_code&), boost::_mfi::dm<void ()(const boost::system::error_code&), kad::ContactList>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<kad::ContactList*> > >, Time = boost::posix_time::ptime, TimeTraits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>, TimerService = boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >]’
../kad/ContactList.cpp:96:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:342: error: invalid use of non-static member function
make: *** [kad/ContactList.o] Error 1
```

I'd really appreciate any help or suggestion.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the compiler is trying (and failing) to tell you the problem is with your constructor. You didn't include the code for it, but I'm guessing you do not initialise the `deadline_timer` member `dt`. Maybe you do something like this:

```
ContactList::ContactList()
{
}
```

The problem is, that the `deadline_timer` class has no default constructor defined - you must choose one of the [defined constructors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/basic_deadline_timer.html). There appear to be three to choose from:

```
basic_deadline_timer(
    boost::asio::io_service & io_service);

basic_deadline_timer(
    boost::asio::io_service & io_service,
    const time_type & expiry_time);

basic_deadline_timer(
    boost::asio::io_service & io_service,
    const duration_type & expiry_time);
```

Obviously the template errors are difficult to read and include a great deal of useless information - parsing them has been something of an art form. You might like to look into installing [stlfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) - it is a set of perl scripts which have the ability to simplify the error messages somewhat.